# Get Json Data when a variable matches with ACF custom field in WooCommerce

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to get data from a json file to be loaded into my WooCommerce website. I would like to get the price from the matching name of the product of the site that I crawled.

I need the name of the product to match the value advanced custom field that I added to the product pages I added into the product page on Wordpress then to get the price if the name matches the attribute I added.

The code below partially worked, but for some reason the call for the advanced custom field value is not working. It displays the value of the text instead of matching it to the name field in json Any advice?

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://gold.explorethatstore.com/wp-content/themes/divi-ETS-child-theme/run_results_apmex.json');

// decode JSON
$json = json_decode($str, true);

// default value
$coinPrice = "Not Available";
$vendorName = the_field('apmex_vendor_name');
// loop the json array
foreach ($json['coin'] as $value){
    // check the condition
    if ($value['name'] == $vendorName){
        $coinPrice = $value['price']; // get the price
        break; // exit the loop
    }
}

echo $coinPrice;
```

Comment: what is the problem here.... does the_field('apmex_vendor_name') not working ? because foreach is working fine in my test

Comment: So the result is that the value of the 'apmex_vendor_name' is printed next to 'Not Available' instead of returning the result of the name of the object matching the 'apmex_vendor_name' field. Am I making sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$vendorName = the_field('apmex_vendor_name');` in your code will not work, because ACF function [the_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) is equivalent of `echo get_field();` which cant work if you want to set the value in a variable…

Instead you should simply use [**`get_field()`**](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/):

```
$vendorName = get_field('apmex_vendor_name');
```

Now it should work…

*The rest of your code seems correct (I have test it)…*

Comment: oh my goodness I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you so much. It worked perfectly. Thank you thank you!

Comment: Thanks again, I am modifying a bit to match a json file that has a slightly different structure to it. when identifying json like this is there a hierarchy? or can php be used to identify the "name" of an object?

Comment: ok so the last issue I am having is with this json file here which is structured slightly different than the first one in my question: http://gold.explorethatstore.com/wp-content/themes/divi-ETS-child-theme/run_results_bgasc.json
I guess my orignial php isn't working on this file, so would my $value change? Im just confused on why it wouldn't be the same function.

Comment: how do I make sure you get the question?

Comment: ok I asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780953/get-json-data-with-matching-advanced-custom-field