# WooCommerce: Get Json data in multi-dimensional array matching ACF custom field

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to get data from this json file, but I need the data that matches the advanced custom field I setup.

```
    $str = file_get_contents('http://gold.explorethatstore.com/wp-content/themes/divi-ETS-child-theme/run_results_bgasc.json');

// decode JSON
$json = json_decode($str, true);

// default value
$coinPrice = "Not Available";
$vendorName = get_field('bgasc_vendor_name');
// loop the json array
foreach($json['coin'] as $value){
        // check the condition
        if($value['coin_name'] == $vendorName){
                $coinPrice = $value['url']; // get the price
                break; // exit the loop
        }
}

echo $coinPrice;
```

Comment: There is a problem as some times for example the category name "Gold American Eagles" has a "weight" array, but "Gold American Buffalos" has not a weight array (1 multi-level-array less)… So that is a problem. All categories names should have the same structure…

Comment: Hmm well that is the way it is crawled on the site, some of the results will come back, and some categories will not have any. the PHP wont identify the array by name?

Comment: my apologies! here it is: http://gold.explorethatstore.com/wp-content/themes/divi-ETS-child-theme/run_results_bgasc_gold.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is the correct code that will handle both array cases (with or without "weight" array):

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://gold.explorethatstore.com/wp-content/themes/divi-ETS-child-theme/run_results_bgasc_gold.json');

// Set te Data in a multi-dimensional array
$json = json_decode($str, true);

// Default variable values
$coin_price = "Not Available";
$url = '';
$break = false;

// Get the vendor name (like the "coin_name" value)
$vendorName = get_field('bgasc_vendor_name');


// Go through multi-dimensional array with multiple loops
foreach ($json['categories'] as $category){
    // Case with "weight" additional array
    if( array_key_exists ( 'weight' , $category ) ){ 
        foreach ($category['weight'] as $weight){
            foreach ($weight['coin'] as $coin){
                // check the condition
                if($coin['coin_name'] == $vendor_name ){
                    $coin_price = $coin['price']; // get the price
                    $url = $coin['url']; // get the url
                    $break = true; // (exit other loops)
                    break; // exit the loop
                }
            }
            if($break) break; // exit the loop
        }
        if($break) break; // exit the loop
    } else { // Case without "weight" additional array
        foreach ($category['coin'] as $coin){
            // check the condition
            if($coin['coin_name'] == $vendor_name ){
                $coin_price = $coin['price']; // get the price
                $url = $coin['url']; // Get the url
                $break = true; // (exit other loops)
                break; // exit the loop
            }
        }
        if($break) break; // exit the loop
    }
}

// output price
echo $coin_price;

// output URL
echo $url;
```

This code is tested and works

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. I see what you did if the "array_key_exists" That makes sense. Thank you very much for all your help. You solved a lot of issues for me today.